# When can I leave a match and still have it count for stats and merits?

Tags: titanfall-2

Most games in Titanfall 2 end with an escape sequence with no respawns.

I noticed that there is no warning message about this match counting as a loss for leaving early if you can no longer respawn.

Does this also mean you will receive merits (exp) and the game is counted towards your stats if you leave the match at this point? Or do you need to finish waiting till all players left / died?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just did some testing, and **yes, you will receive merits** after leaving the match as long as the win/loss has been decided.

Keep in mind that when you leave the match early, you will also be removed from your party if you have one.

Comment: I don't know if this is the same if you lost connection (i.e. connection error).  I definitely didn't retain progress to challenges and xp levels when the server dropped during games in the original Titanfall.  However, leaving the game early always seemed fine for all kinds of progression (xp, medals, achievement progress etc).